# How to start AI-Platform jobs automatically?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-training

I created a training job where I fetch my data from big query, perform training and deploy model. I would like to start training automatically in this two cases:

1. More than 1000 new rows added to the dataset
2. With a schedule (Ex, once a week)

I checked GCP Cloud Scheduler, but it seems its not suitable for my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud Scheduler is the right tool to trigger your training on a schedule. *I don't know what your blocker is!!*

For your first point, you can't. You can't put a trigger (on BigQuery or on other database) to send an event after X new rows. For this, I recommend you to do this:

- Schedule a job with Cloud Scheduler (for example every 10 minutes)
- The job perform a request in BigQuery and check the number of line since the last training job (the date of the last training job must be somewhere, I recommend in another BigQuery table)

  - If the number of line is > 1000, trigger your running job
  - Else, exit the function

As you see, it's not so easy and there is several caveats:

- When you deploy your model, you also have to write the date of the latest training
- You have to perform several times the request into BigQuery. Partition correctly your table for limiting the cost

Does it make sense for you?

**EDIT**

gcloud command is a "simple" wrapper of API calls. Try to add the param `--http-log` to your gcloud command to see which API is called and with which params.

Anyway, you can start a job by calling this [API](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs/create), and if you want and example, use the `--http-log` param of gcloud SDK!

Comment: Cloud Scheduler targets are HTTP, Pub/Sub and App Engine HTTP but in order to create AI-Platform Jobs, I need gcloud command.

Comment: No, you needn't. I edited my answer with more details.

Comment: I didn't know that part, I think this is the answer, thanks a lot

Comment: Did you manage to run this? We're trying to deploy something very similar, but are running into a blocker: we configured Google Scheduler to run the training job via the REST API... but then, job training requires a unique job name. is there a way to provide such unique name from the Scheduler?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking for solution to submit training job on schedule,Here I am posting my solution after trying few ways.I tried,

- Run through cloud composer using Airflow
- Start job using start script
- Use cron with Cloud scheduler,Pub/Sub and Cloud function

Easiest and most cost effective way is using cloud scheduler and AI-platform client library with cloud function

step 1 -  create pub/sub topic (example `start-training`)

step 2 -  create cron using cloud scheduler targeting `start-training` topic

[image]

step 3 - create cloud function using trigger type as `cloud pub/sub` and topic as `start-training` and entry point is `submit_job` function.This function submit a training job to AI-platform through python client library.

Now we have this beautiful DAG

**Scheduler -> Pub/Sub -> Cloud Function -> AI-platform**

cloud function code goes like this

***main.py***

```
import datetime
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

id = '<PROJECT ID>'
bucket_name = "<BUCKET NAME>"
project_id = 'projects/{}'.format(id)
job_name = "training_" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y%m%d_%H%M%S")

def submit_job(event, context):

     training_inputs = {
     'scaleTier': 'BASIC',
     'packageUris': [f"gs://{bucket_name}/package/trainer-0.1.tar.gz"],
     'pythonModule': 'trainer.task',
     'region': 'asia-northeast1',
     'jobDir': f"gs://{bucket_name}",
     'runtimeVersion': '2.2',
     'pythonVersion': '3.7',
          }

     job_spec = {"jobId":job_name, "trainingInput": training_inputs}
     cloudml = discovery.build("ml" , "v1" ,cache_discovery=False)
     request = cloudml.projects().jobs().create(body=job_spec,parent=project_id)
     response = request.execute()
```

***requirement.txt***

```
google-api-python-client
oauth2client
```

**Important**

- make sure to use **Project_id** not ***Project_name***,otherwise it will give permission error
- If you get `ImportError:file_cache is unavailable when using oauthclient ....` error use `cache_discovery=False` in build function,otherwise leave function to use cache for performance reason.
- point to correct GCS location to your source package,in this case my package name is `trainer` built and located in `package` folder in the bucket and main module is `task`

Comment: Hi! Do you know have to pass custom arguments in this method? I am using custom dockers and would like to pass `--epochs 5` as outlined here: https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/custom-containers-training